# How to synchronize access to resources in parent window when accessing from child window?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

When I have a resource (e.g. a global variable `foo`) that exists in javascript running in a browser window, and I then access that variable from a child window via `window.opener.foo`, how do I synchronize access to this, so that the parent and child window do not run into race conditions when using the variable simultaneously?

We obviously run into this issue frequently when writing multithreaded code, but in languages that support multithreading, we typically have synchronization mechanisms to ensure safe access to shared resources.  However, no such synchronization mechanisms exist in javascript since it is a single threaded environment.

However, in the case of multiple windows accessing a shared variable via `window.opener`, we have two separate javascript runtime environments that are NOT guaranteed to run on a single thread.  So how do we ensure safe access to the shared variables?  I could not find information on this by Googling, but maybe I wasn't using the correct search criteria.